We face a situation "that" we have to eat only vegetables for days "in". - just like how we describe a normal location?
Case, situation, and other words like that are kind of treated like a more abstract location when followed by an adjective clause. So, the connector can be in which/where, like the following.
Example 1

We face a situation in which/where we have to eat only vegetables for days.

Example 2

We witnessed a crazy case in which/where the guy got so drunk that he danced in the middle of the street.

Do they follow the same rules as a normal, physical location does?

from Understanding and Using English Grammar by Betty S. Azar and Stacy A. Hagen
For instance,
Example 3

We face a situation that we have to eat only vegetables for days in.

Example 4

We witnessed a crazy case that the guy got so drunk that he danced in the middle of the street in.


3 is marginal at best and 4 is ungrammatical.  Use where there too.

I add to what @TimR said.
Example 3 sounds unnatural:

a situation that we have to eat only vegetables for days in

We should shift in to front the relative clause but can’t do so with that; that cannot be object of the preposition.  We need which:
a situation where (or in which) we have to eat only vegetables for days
Example 4 is ungrammatical:

a crazy case that the guy got so drunk that he danced in the middle of the street in

The last preposition in belongs to the first relative clause:

a crazy case that the guy got so drunk in that he danced in the middle of the street

This still sounds unnatural, and hence I do the same as in example 3:

a crazy case where (or in which) the guy got so drunk that he danced in the middle of the street

